# Stop ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging from interfering with structured logs

Tags: ruby, logging, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-6

`ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging` works by appending `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter` to the inheritance chain of the current formatter via `Object#extend`.

Unfortunately, `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter#call`
assumes the `msg` argument is always a string, resulting in
garbage when it prepends tags to a hash (e.g. with Lograge and [Ougai](https://github.com/tilfin/ougai)). And certain standard libraries, like [Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb#L77), insist on injecting `TaggedLogging`.

I've come up with the metaprogramming hack below to prevent `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter#call` from overriding the superclass implementation (in this case from Ougai):

```rb
class MyBunyanFormatter < Ougai::Formatters::Bunyan
  def extend(mod)
    return super unless mod.method_defined?(:call)

    call_original = self.method(:call)            # 1. preserve original
    super(mod)                                    # 2. overridden here
    define_singleton_method(:call, call_original) # 3. de-overridden here
  end
end
```

But it's clunky and counterintuitive, and I'm not excited about it.

The other alternative, [at least in the case of Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb#L74), seems to be to write a custom logger that implements `tagged()`:

```rb
class MyLogger < Ougai::Logger
  def tagged(*tags)
    # do something with tags
    yield self
  end
end
```

This at least doesn't involve any metaprogramming shenanigans, but I wonder if I can count on other libraries besides Webpacker not to inject `TaggedLogging` anyway.

Surely I'm not the first person to have this problem since people started trying to do structured logging from Rails apps. What's the right solution?

Answer (score 2):

The solution given in the [Ougai docs](https://github.com/tilfin/ougai/wiki/Use-as-Rails-logger#with-activesupporttaggedlogging) is to monkey-patch `TaggedLogging` to eliminate this behavior.

```rb
module ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, data)
    data = { msg: data.to_s } unless data.is_a?(Hash)
    tags = current_tags
    data[:tags] = tags if tags.present?
    _call(severity, time, progname, data)
  end
end
```

Note that `_call` only works if for Ougai-based `Formatters`.